# VBA: how to pass a form as a paramter

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a simple user form with a button on it. I want to pass this form to a function in another module - but even inside the same module, it does not work as expected:

```
Private Sub Test(ByRef oForm As MSForms.UserForm)
    Debug.Print "caption: >" & oForm.Caption & "<"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Debug.Print "caption: >" & Me.Caption & "<"
    Test Me
    Debug.Print "caption: >" & Me.Caption & "<"
End Sub
```

when I click the button it prints this to the debug console:

```
caption: >UserForm1<
caption: ><
caption: >UserForm1<
```

so inside of the `Test()` sub the `Caption` is blank.

any ideas why this does not work?

Note: if I use `Variant` as parameter-type it works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type `UserForm` is not directly equivalent to an instance of a specific User Form and presents a slightly different interface.

Pass the form `as Object`:

```
Private Sub Test(Form As Object)
```

or for a type safe approach a UserForm may implement an Interface:

```
Private Sub Test(Form As IMyForm)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on the second approach? Do you mean create an interface which holds the properties and methods that will be used in Test method and then implement this interface in my custom form?

Comment: Yes exactly that, so `IMyForm` has a `.Caption` property that within an implementing form wraps `Me.Caption`.

Comment: how does one know that it's "slightly different"? is this documented somewhere? i.e. the Properties view in the VBE shows that my form is of type `UserForm` and also this test is true: `TypeOf Me Is MSForms.UserForm`. And since MSForms.UserForm has a Caption property , so I don't understand why it does not work.

Comment: Well the autocomplete properties for UserForm and UserForm1 are different, much more exposed for the latter.

Comment: Can you direct me to how one would implement an interface? Class Module?

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was the following...

1) Define a global parameter in the main module as follows:

```
Public gMyForm As MSForms.UserForm
```

2) In the UserForm_Initialize() sub:

```
Set gMyForm = Me
```

3) To call the function:

```
Dim l_dummy as Variant
l_dummy = myFunction(gMyForm)
```

4) Function signature plus a few lines of random code:

```
Function myFunction(ByRef p_form As MSForms.UserForm) 

Dim l_my_value type string
l_my_value = p_form.myControl.Value
```

The only weirdness, which doubtless someone can explain, is the need to specify the l_dummy return parameter else you get the type mismatch error.  Worked like a charm otherwise..

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a variable of your UserForm's type. It means that if your form's name is `MyForm` then the signature shoud be

```
Private Sub Test(ByRef oForm As MyForm)
```

Comment: I cannot use this, because I pass the form to a function in another VBA project (which does not know about the concrete type)

Comment: Take a look what happens when you set the form's caption to something inside `Test`. That's odd.

Answer (score 0):

> "The only weirdness, which doubtless someone can explain, is the need
> to specify the l_dummy return parameter else you get the type mismatch
> error. Worked like a charm otherwise.. Hope this helps someone."

These are features of the language syntax.
You use the function, but do not specify the type of return value.
If you don't need to return anything then use Sub().
Brackets must be specified if the function returns something :

```
variant ret = myFunction(gMyForm)
```

if it doesn't return:

```
myFunction gMyForm
```

to avoid creating unnecessary variables:
not return:  `myFunction Me`
return:`... = myFunction(Me)`
Signature Method/Function:

```
Sub myFunction(p_form As MyForm)
........
End Sub
```

Or

```
Function myFunction(p_form As MyForm) As Variant
............
   myFunction = p_form.myControl.Value
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution I found. The important parts are:

1. At the Call site into the `Sub`, the `Call`  is required IF THE ARGUMENT IS WITHIN PARENTHESIS. When I left out `Call`  and kept the parenthesis around the argument, I received an error of `Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method`. And when selecting "Debug" in the error dialog, I am dropped into the VBA editor and it indicates the `.Visible` reference within the `Sub` itself is what was not found. The error disappears when the parenthesis around the argument is removed.
2. Within the `Sub`, the parameter accepting the form, `pv_objFrmTarget`, must be defined as `ByVal`. It explicitly cannot be defined as `ByRef` or left undefined (which defaults to `ByRef`). When I used `ByRef` or left it out, I received an error of `Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch`. And when selecting "Debug" in the error dialog, I am dropped into the VBA editor and it indicates the `Call s_...` statement is in error (as in it is attempting to update the `ByRef` value following the completion of the call).
3. Within the `Sub`, the type of the parameter accepting the form, `pv_objFrmTarget`, must be defined as either `As Object` or `As Variant` or not defined at all (which I believe results in defaulting to `As Variant`). Defining it as 'UserForm' results in an error of `Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method`. And when selecting "Debug" in the error dialog, I am dropped into the VBA editor and it indicates the `.Visible` reference within the `Sub` itself is what was not found.

---

**Solution 1:**

Code at Call Site:

```
Sub btnClear_Click()
  Call s_FrmShowCenteredOnlyIfHidden(frmClear)
End Sub
```

Code at `Sub` Site:

```
Public Sub s_FrmShowCenteredOnlyIfHidden(ByVal pv_objFrmTarget As Object)
  With pv_objFrmTarget
    If (.Visible = False) Then
      .StartUpPosition = 0
      .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
      .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
      .Show
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

---

**Solution 2: [all defaults]**

Code at Call Site:

```
Sub btnClear_Click()
  s_FrmShowCenteredOnlyIfHidden frmClear
End Sub
```

Code at `Sub` Site:

```
Public Sub s_FrmShowCenteredOnlyIfHidden(ByVal pv_objFrmTarget)
  With pv_objFrmTarget
    If (.Visible = False) Then
      .StartUpPosition = 0
      .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
      .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
      .Show
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Pass the userform as *Object*, like here:

```
..
Call Subroutine(Me)
..

Sub Subroutine(Dialog As Object)
    Dim UF As Object
    Set UF = Dialog
    Debug.Print Dialog.caption, UF.caption
End Sub
```

Comment: and how is that different to the accepted answer - except for the useless `UF` variable?